# Extract inner content from a string

Tags: jquery, css, string, transform

Here is the problem I am facing - I am having a div called ('myDiv'). And I have set a setInterval function, It runs every 2second. What i want is each time when setInterval will execute, I want to rotate the div '15deg' extra.

I did almost. But when I am doing some string manipulation, it is getting wrong.
//here is the code.

//css transform required value = 15ddeg not '15deg'
so how to extract '15deg' to 15deg (without qoute)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script>

      $(function(){
        var foo = setInterval('animateDiv()', 2000);
    var count = 15;

    function animateDiv(){
       //console.log(count);

    count += 10;

       $('.myDiv').css({'-webkit-transform':'rotate(count + "deg")'});

      //console.log(count + "deg");
    }
      });

</script> 
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='myDiv'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: never use `setInterval`/`setTimeout` with a string, because then they use the devil `eval`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/RWQSC/

```
(function(){
        var intId = setInterval(animateDiv, 2000),
            count = 15,
            $myDiv = $('.myDiv'); //Cache the div so we don't keep looking though the DOM for the same element. 

    function animateDiv(){
       console.log(count);
       count += 10;
       $myDiv.css({'-webkit-transform':'rotate(' + count +'deg)'});
       //console.log(count + "deg");
    }

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems,

First, setting your transform, you are literally using the string 'count' in the value string, you need to concat the value of `count` to the string instead of just using the string:

```
$('.myDiv').css({'-webkit-transform':'rotate('+count+'deg)'});
```

Second, you are getting a JavaScript console error that it cannot find function `animateDiv`, since your function is not a global one, and is actually inside the on-load event, you can't find it by string name that way, instead, try just passing in the function directly (note, don't include the parentheses, we don't want to invoke the function, we are just assigning it as the parameter):

```
var foo = setInterval(animateDiv, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't get your problem but you can do this like this way

```
var index = deg.indexOf('\'');
var LastIndex = deg.LastIndexOf('\'');
deg = deg.substring(index+1,LastIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
function animateDiv() {
    // console.log(count);

    count += 10;

    $('.myDiv').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + count + 'deg)'
    });

    //console.log(count + "deg");
}

var count = 15;
var foo = setInterval(animateDiv, 500);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xxc5/)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/3LKXC/)

```
var count = 15;

function animateDiv(){
    count += 10;
    $('#myDiv').css({'-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + count + 'deg)'});
    console.log('rotate(' + count + 'deg)');
}

var foo = setInterval(animateDiv, 2000);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want maximum speed, you shouldn't use jQuery, and you should cache your element outside `animateDiv`.

And never use `setInterval`/`setTimeout` with a string, because then they use the devil `eval`!

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0],
    count = 15,
    foo = setInterval(animateDiv, 2000);
function animateDiv(){
    count += 10;
    el.style.transform = 'rotate('+count + 'deg)';
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/thdyL/1/

**Edit**:

If you want to increase speed even more (but you will lose readability), you can also use

```
var style = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0].style,
    count = 15,
    foo = setInterval(animateDiv, 2000);
function animateDiv(){
    style.transform = 'rotate('+ (count += 10) + 'deg)';
}
```

And you should consider using `id` instead of `class`, given that it's only one element.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it because I say *If you want maximum speed, you shouldn't use jQuery* ? Oh no, [jQuery is taking over the world!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)